# How to add the citation keys to the bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

How can I add the citation key to the bibliography?

Let's take this entry as an example:

```
@book{Fowler1999,
  address = {Boston, MA, USA},
  author = {Fowler, Martin},
  description = {AOEvolutionchapter short paper},
  isbn = {0-201-48567-2},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  title = {Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code},
  year = 1999
}
```

I would now want the bibliography in my PDF document to look like this:

[Fowler1999] Martin Fowler. *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code*. Addison-Wesley,
Boston, MA, USA, 1999. ISBN 0-201-48567-2.

Can someone please help me? I'm using **natbib** and bibliographystyle **plainnat**.
And since it's the last day before deadline and I'm not that familiar with LaTeX, I'd prefer a solution where I don't need to change those two...

**EDIT:**
apparently I did not express myself well. 
I don't want those keys in the text. 
There I already have them. 
I want them to appear in my bibliography as well.

Instead of:

`Martin Fowler. Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code. Addison-Wesley,
Boston, MA, USA, 1999. ISBN 0-201-48567-2.`

I want:

`[Fowler1999] Martin Fowler. Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code. Addison-Wesley,
Boston, MA, USA, 1999. ISBN 0-201-48567-2.`

Note that Fowler1999 is the citation key I used.

Comment: Are you using `natbib`? In this case you could use the `authoryear` option, assumed you have the keys like that in your bib-file.

Comment: @Habi yeah, I'm using natbib. How do I enable this authoryear option?

Comment: Don't crosspost.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `authoryear` and `square` options of [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib), the keys in your text show up as desired, if you use the `\citep`-command

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{library.bib}
@book{Fowler1999,
  address = {Boston, MA, USA},
  author = {Fowler, Martin},
  description = {AOEvolutionchapter short paper},
  isbn = {0-201-48567-2},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  title = {Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code},
  year = 1999
}

@book{Doe2000,
  address = {Somewhere},
  author = {Doe, John},
  title = {Awesome title},
  year = 2000
}
\end{filecontents}

\setcitestyle{aysep={}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\citep{Fowler1999}

\blindtext\cite{Doe2000}

\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\end{document}
```

Or you could use the `alpha` bibliography style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{library.bib}
@book{Fowler1999,
  address = {Boston, MA, USA},
  author = {Fowler, Martin},
  description = {AOEvolutionchapter short paper},
  isbn = {0-201-48567-2},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  title = {Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code},
  year = 1999
}

@book{Doe2000,
  address = {Somewhere},
  author = {Doe, John},
  title = {Awesome title},
  year = 2000
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\cite{Fowler1999}

\blindtext\cite{Doe2000}

\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess I did not express myself well. I don't want those keys in the text. There I already have them. I want them to appear in my bibliography as well. Instead of `Martin Fowler. Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code. Addison-Wesley,
Boston, MA, USA, 1999. ISBN 0-201-48567-2.` I want `[Fowler1999] Martin Fowler. Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code. Addison-Wesley,
Boston, MA, USA, 1999. ISBN 0-201-48567-2.`

Comment: In this case you can use the 'alpha' style, as mentioned in the second example of my answer. If that does not suit you, you can generate a style for yourself, either with `makebst` or the graphical user-interface to it here: http://www.podoblaz.net/cml/?id=39

Comment: Or take a look at this question/answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10464/ or this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35306/